# Refactoring code with XMLHttp and Eventlistener to fetch()

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a working code of the modal window in which the user enters the phone number, and after clicking goes to processing requests on the local server, which, depending on the request code, should give some information.

Can't understand how this record type is converted to fetch(). I tried to redo the MDN code, but there is an error in two cases - when send (json) is initialized and for some reason it doesn't work to hang this handler on addEventListener('readystatechange')

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    form.appendChild(statusMessage);

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', 'server.php');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    let formData = new FormData(form); 
    let obj = {};
    formData.forEach(function(value, key){ 
        obj[key] = value;
    });

    let json = JSON.stringify(obj); 

    request.send(json);


    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){ 
        if (request.readyState < 4){
            statusMessage.innerHTML = message.loading;
        } else if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            statusMessage.innerHTML = message.success;
        } else {
            statusMessage.innerHTML = message.failure;
        };
    });
});
```

Are there any recommendations for refactoring such a code into today's standart?

Below is the code I got

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    form.appendChild(statusMessage);

    let formData = new FormData(form); 
    let obj = {};
    formData.forEach(function(value, key){ 
        obj[key] = value;
    });
        let response = fetch('/server.php', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
            body: JSON.stringify(obj)
        })



    response.then(() => {
                if (response.readyState < 4){
                    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.loading;
                }
            })
            .then(() => {if(response.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                statusMessage.innerHTML = message.success;
            }})
            .catch(()=>statusMessage.innerHTML = message.failure );
});
```

Comment: Whats your question, what problem are you hitting..?

Comment: use `load` event instead of `readystatechange` ... or use fetch - it already returns a promise

Comment: It would help if you showed your attempt at conversion, then we could see specific things which might be wrong

Comment: I have some issues when try to use fetch() method. One of them - json.stringify() was used like independent variable, when i try to use fetch() it going in body block, and can`t get in mind how use it. Second thing - what is alternate way for readyState in fetch().

Comment: Added my try to convert into fetch(), but when i try use it with EventListener nothing works

Comment: Any particular reason you added an extra `/` before server.php in the URL? Maybe it's failing due to the wrong path. Have you checked in your browser's network tools to see what is happening? P.s. the equivalent to readystate 
success is the .done()  callback - it will run that callback if the response is ok, or the catch callback if the response includes an error status, it is all based on the Promise interface, so if you don't have experience of Promises you should study that as well

Comment: I noticed that the server is not working, does not send requests for itself, there are no errors in the code. I still don't see where the problem is

Comment: If you have a problem with your server code you'll have to show it here if you want help with it. We can't guess what error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readyState` is not used in `fetch()`. Instead you can use `.done()` to provide a callback to be executed when the returned status is a successful one (e.g. 200, 201), and `.catch()` to provide a callback for when the status is a failure (e.g. 4xx, 500).

The basics of your conversion should be as follows:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  form.appendChild(statusMessage);

  let formData = new FormData(form); 
  let obj = {};
  formData.forEach(function(value, key){ 
    obj[key] = value;
  });

  let response = fetch('server.php', {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
     body: JSON.stringify(obj)
  });

  response.done(function(responseData) {
    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.success;
  })
  .catch(function(errorData) { 
    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.failure; 
  });
});
```

Comment: It's already very close, but I noticed that **done ()** - doesn't work in this case, but **fetch ()** seems to be working. The problem is that the response from the 405 server is considered correct. Code for my server                                             **<?php 

echo $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR‘];**

Comment: 405 is an error status, so I'd expect it to go into the catch() instead, that seems correct. It your server is sending a 405 (Method not allowed) status then either you need to fix the server, or you need to check whether your URL is supposed to accept a GET or a POST (or another method) and amend the fetch setting accordingly